# EF 5 not saving changes on calling save changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, dbcontext, savechanges

I am using EF 5 in VS 2012. I am trying to save a new record to a table but is not getting saved in the table and also no error is thrown. Please help . I am attaching my code.

```
using (TestEntities context = new TestEntities(new TestEntityConnectionManager("Testconn").ConnectionString))
            {
                var newCan = new Can
                {
                    CanGUID = new Guid(canGuid),
                    CanName = canName,
                    CanDescription = canDescription,
                    DesignCandidateID = designCandidateId,
                    MigrationDataXml = migrationDataXml,
                    PersonID =  1,
                    LastModifiedPersonID = 1,
                    CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
                    LastModifiedDate = DateTime.Now,

                };
                context.Cans.AddObject(newCan);
                var paramOut =  context.SaveChanges();
                retval = paramOut.ToString();
```

Comment: Can you show the whole method?  I don't see anything glaring, other that is seems you are using the ObjectContext version and it is recommended to use DbContext.

Comment: Hi Justin, there is nothing else in this method, method has some parameters which I pass as value to new newCan class as shown above in my code snippet

Comment: Put it into try catch and please tell us what the exception is

Comment: AddObject is not a method on `IDbSet` (ef 5), either you are posting the wrong code or you should be using `.Add` instead

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look right,

`var paramOut =  context.SaveChanges();`

Should be in your `[HttpPost]` method surrounded by `if (ModelState.IsValid)`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CLASS Model)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
                db.Table.Add(Model);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(Model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If no errors are occured and no data is saved, the problem must be in your connection string.

In fact, it seems that your conStr doesn't connect to the database you want! And db initializer is created a new database (because of your custom conStr) and save the data in it.